# Correcting Video Orientation in iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, video, avfoundation, avmutablecomposition

I am developing a video app in which user can merge different videos present in Asset Library. I am able to join the videos but I am facing the orientation issues.
For example, if a video is landscape right and other is landscape left, the second video will be joined upside down. Moreover, I have tried different codes available at stackExchange, however if i apply those codes to portrait videos, they can be transformed to landscape right but leaving black margins on the sides.

Is there any way that when I select a video to be inserted in my project, first its orientation should be checked, if it is other then landscape right, it should be rotated accordingly and in the end if the original video was portrait, the  video should be resized as the native player do when we play a video in full screen mode.

Thanks in advance.